# how to close ajax modal popup with clicking outside

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, modalpopupextender

I am writing a web page in c# asp.net . The page is using a master page . I have an ajax modal popup window in the page. I want to add 2 features for this popup:

- Close the popup when user clicks outside the modal popup
- Trigger a serverside code after modal popup is closed.

There are similar questions on stackoverflow but almost all of them are related to jquery modal popups.

here is my code:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Style="display: none" />
    <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" OkControlID="btnOkay"
        TargetControlID="Button1" PopupControlID="Panel1" PopupDragHandleControlID="PopupHeader"
        Drag="true" BackgroundCssClass="ModalPopupBG">
    </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="PopupCss">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <table style="width: 100%; height: 825px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div id="mediaplayer">
                                JW Player goes here</div>
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                                jwplayer("mediaplayer").setup({
                                    flashplayer: "jwplayer/player.swf",
                                    file: "<%=videoName %>",
                                    image: "<%=videoThumb %>",
                                    width: "100%",
                                    height: "100%"
                                });
                            </script>
                        </td>
                        <td valign="top" align="left" style="text-align: left;">
                            <div class="fb-like" data-send="true" data-layout="button_count" data-show-faces="true">
                            </div>
                            <br />
                            <div class="fb-comments" data-href="<%=videoLink%>" data-num-posts="3" data-width="470">
                            </div>
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
                            <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
                                <a class="addthis_button_preferred_1"></a><a class="addthis_button_preferred_2">
                                </a><a class="addthis_button_preferred_3"></a><a class="addthis_button_preferred_4">
                                </a><a class="addthis_button_compact"></a><a class="addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-4f61d99d08697325"></script>
                            <!-- AddThis Button END -->
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <asp:Rating ID="Rating1" runat="server" MaxRating="5" StarCssClass="ratingStar" FilledStarCssClass="ratingStarFilled"
                                AutoPostBack="false" OnChanged="VideoRatingChanged" EmptyStarCssClass="ratingStarEmpty"
                                WaitingStarCssClass="ratingStarEmpty">
                                <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value='<%=videoId%>' />
                            </asp:Rating>
                            &nbsp (<%=voteCount%>)
                            <br />
                            Minder Score:
                            <%=minderScore %>
                            <br />
                            <div class="Controls" style="text-align: left;">
                                <input id="btnOkay" type="button" value="Kapat" />
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </asp:Panel>
```

and in the code behind i show the popup with this line:

```
ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to create your pop-up

Comment: @Jupaol I added the code. The panel has a video with social plugin, a rating control and facebook comment plugin. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

to hide / show modalpopuextender using javascript, pls try:

```
function hidemodal() {
$find('ModalPopupExtender1').hide();
}

function showmodal() {
$find('ModalPopupExtender1').show();
}
```

you can raise that hidemodal() method on click event or else.

Also you can add code inside hidemodal() method with calling a server side script from javascript using ***PageMethods*** to triggers server side function. Find on net about asp.net PageMethods

```
function hidemodal() {
$find('ModalPopupExtender1').hide();
PageMethods.AnyServerFunction(param, onsuccess_callback);
}

function onsuccess_callback() {
}
```

Regards,

Comment: hi, how can i bind the clicking outside of the modal to the hidemodal function and where do i call that function ? Thanks.

Comment: I think it is hard to click outside of modal because the nature of modalpopup is preventing parent to be accessed before modal is closed. One way i can think of is catching ESC key at body / form keydown event i.e <body onkeydown="hidemodal()" > with javascript: function hidemodal() {
            var keycode = window.event.keyCode;
            if (keycode == 27) {
                $find("ModalPopupExtender1").hide();
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the `click` event on the body, and set `e.stopPropagation();` inside the click, after that you can check if the clicked element is the popup element, if it is, do nothing, if it's not, close the popup